Bend curve along a surface
How to bend BezierCurve along a surface?


A simple method is to create a new mesh with a single vertex, enable vertex snapping, extrude and snap vertices on the surface of the model as desired, then in Object mode right click and choose Convert to > Curve.


Is it possible to select a edge in this way and turn it into a curve?

Yes, select it, Shift D to duplicate, P to separate into a new object, then right click to convert to a curve.

Thanks, did it.
